# Embed console application in Windows Form and use as process?

Tags: .net, vb.net, resources, embed, embedded-resource

I'm trying to consolidate my application's dependencies. In this case, I have a console application (MAD - MPEG Audio Decoder) that I want to embed into my application. I've added it as a resource, but how can I reference it as a file? This is the code in question (VB.NET):

```
With MAD.StartInfo
    .FileName = My.Resources.madplay
    .Arguments = ""
    .UseShellExecute = False
    .RedirectStandardInput = True
    .RedirectStandardError = True
    .RedirectStandardOutput = True
End With
MAD.Start()
MAD.BeginOutputReadLine()
```

Obviously this does not work. I need to reference My.Resources.madplay as a file for FileName. Is there a way to do this, or should I copy the resource to disc and delete it after I'm done?

Comment: Yes, you will need to write it out as a file before you can execute it.

Comment: I ended up using WriteAllBytes() to write it out to a file, then deleting it afterwards. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**The best practice is really to move the code that does the work out of your console application into a class library (DLL file), and then import that DLL into both your WinForms project and your console application project.**

That will still accomplish your goal of consolidating code by putting all of your audio decoding logic into a single library that is used by both applications, but also allows you to separate the display functionality (however minimal it may be in the console app) that *does* differ between both apps.

Otherwise, you're not going to be able to execute a file that exists as an embedded resource without extracting it into a file. I suppose you could do this into a temporary directory, but then you'll be left with the not-so-trivial task of getting the window handle and trying to host it in the Windows Form. Most of the ways you'll find to do this reek of a hack, and I find it hard to believe that your users will appreciate a console app being thrown at them when they're using an otherwise nicely-designed Windows Form.
And again, if all you're trying to do is make the common functionality for decoding audio available in both apps by *calling* that code from the console application behind the scenes in the WinForms app, placing it into a dynamically-linked library is by far your best solution.

Comment: My WinForm GUI application is calling the console application and running it as a separate process. I was simply wondering if I could, instead of distributing it as a separate file, call it from My.Resources. I ended up using WriteAllBytes() to write it out to a file, then deleting it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using WriteAllBytes() to write it out to a file, then deleting it afterwards.